# Wordpress “PHP inside of PHP“ – Integrate qTranslate with Meta Box

Tags: php, wordpress, date, meta-boxes, qtranslate

For a Website (Wordpress) I want to display dates with the well-known plugin Meta Box and the Website should be provided in English as well as in German, with the plugin qTranslate.

German and English date formats are different: German: dd.mm.y (31.12.16), English: mm/dd/y (12/31/16). So to display the right format according to the language chosen by/for the visitor, the two plugins need to work together.

This is how I would display the date without any language option:

```
<?php echo rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginning' ); ?>
```

This is how I would display translating text on the website outside of the post- and page-contents (like the site navigation):

```
<?php _e("[:en]Current[:de]Aktuell[:]"); ?>
```

My question now is, how I can join the two functions. If it helps, I would be fine with splitting the exhibition_meta_beginning in exhibition_meta_beginning_DE and exhibition_meta_beginning_EN, which would mean that I had to enter every date twice when creating a new instance/post, one in German and once in English format.

I haven't found anything useful yet – yes, there are mentions of that and there is some kind of way to use Custom Fields (which is the core basis of Meta Box) with qTranslate, but nothing seems to work and my knowledge in PHP is the bare minimum.

The input fields for the meta data being dates (and times) are defined in a separate PHP file like this (standard Meta Box procedure):

```
array(
        'name'      => 'Beginn der Ausstellung',
        'id'        => $prefix . 'beginn',
        'type'      => 'date',
        'format'    => 'dd.mm.y'
    ),
```

Neither did it work to implement the bilinguality into the format value right there (it thinks that it is a date's format not a language tag when [:en]... appears there), nor something like that in the part where the data is displayed (sorry for the amateurish attempt):

```
<?php __("[:en] echo rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginn_EN' )[:de]echo rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginn_DE' )[:]"); ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The solution at the end was to use `date_i18n` (look up on Wordpress Codex). Have the date field defined with an universal date format that can be read by `strtotime` (e.g.`yy-mm-dd`) and use that as an argument in `date_i18n`. Use `date_i18n` twice, one for the English format and one for the other format, join them with the appropriate language tags as strings and `.` in between to connect. Then use `_e` to echo the whole string, that uses the content of one input field twice in two interpretations (two languages) and the final locale will choose which one to display. Exquisite solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
$en = rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginn_EN' );
$de = rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginn_DE' );
echo __('[:en]'.$en.'[:de]'.$de.'[:]');
```

or create a function that return the value based on language

```
function __show_based_on_lang($en, $de) {
    return ( qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'en') ? $en : $de ;
}
```

then to use the function you can just have it like this,

```
echo __show_based_on_lang( rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginn_EN' ), rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginn_DE' ) );
```

Comment: Awesome. That is working. I don't want to seem greedy, but would you also have an idea on how to solve the issue without splitting all values in two?

Comment: Just save the whole syntax in single meta field, then it will be automatically converted and you only need to echo the metabox field value which is  ```[:en]English[:de]German Value[:]```

Comment: I am not at work right now, so I can't try again, but if I understand correctly, this is what I tried and writing the qtranslate syntax into the meta box field (type=date) results in interpreting "de" and "en" as PHP date syntax, so it returns numbers like the day for 'd'.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if your meta fields isn't a simple text input field  (like checkbox, or datapicker )  then you can just integrate a text domain translation directly into it (assuming it supports translation)

Comment: text domain translation? what does that mean? and what "it" has to support translation? The problem that I mean, is, that the value in the field that is interpreted as a date (date picker with specified date format) interprets the whole value and doesn't exclude stuff that is in brackets or comment syntax, it just takes it either as a string or, if specified, as a format symbol. So instead of 'de' it interprets 'd' as the day number with a leading 0 and the 'e' as the the time zone used. Or – if you mean something else – could you give me a code sample? Thank you!

Comment: check this out
https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75759/what-is-a-theme-textdomain

Comment: Whenever I try PHP it just returns a blank page... Okay, so I changed the initial date format in the date picker to the neutral UNIX time format being mm/dd-yy (or m/d-Y, but that didn't work). Then I wrote 

< ? php 
                    $beginn = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_beginn' ) );
                    $ende = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( rwmb_meta( 'exhibition_meta_ende' ) ); 
                    echo __( $beginn.'–'.$ende );
                                     ? >

Sorry you have to c/p it somewhere to have syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102112/discussion-between-thomas-maier-and-silver).